# How to replace https with http for images url to be shown correctly?

Tags: flutter

How to convert this image url
https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg
to this image url 
http://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the configuration for the site you wont be able to change the link since it is a hosted image and you are just linking to where it is hosted.

If you are trying to show it in your flutter app you can try using Image.network:

`Image.network('https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg'),`

This works with the link you have provided.

Comment: the problem with me in json url there object image as https not http so can't add image to package.yaml

Comment: {
    "id": 389,
    "title": "Hikechangers ",
    "img": [
        "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg",
        "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432315268827.jpg",
        "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432445581923.jpg",
        "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432574644899.jpg"
    ],
    
}.  this is json object for image

Comment: Are you trying to show the images in your app? Can you provide some code to show what you are trying to do with the URL so it is more clear what you are asking.

Comment: I need display https://  skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg in image finally https not display image in app and to solve this echo I want convert  https:// skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg    to http://  skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg

Comment: I updated the solution with a way to show images in your app using a URL, this works with https links. There is no way for you to convert the link from HTTPS to HTTP since the host of the image is using HTTPS. If Image.network doesnt work can you please show a screenshot of your error output?

Comment: Did using Image.network fix your problem? If so dont forget to accept the answer so the question is closed.

Comment: Can you post code showing where you are trying to display the image?

Comment: course.img = [
      "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg",
      "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432315268827.jpg",
      "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432445581923.jpg",
      "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432574644899.jpg"
    ];     there https://.  before skillzycp.com

Comment: Carousel(
                boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                images: [
                  Image.network(
                    course.img[0],
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 100,
                    height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 40,
                  ),)

Comment: Can you add it and your json code as an edit on your question and inside a code format block so it is easier to read?

Comment: ' course.img = [
      "https://skillzycp.com/upload/business/389_636896432064799384.jpg"
    ];   Carousel(
                boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                images: [
                  Image.network(
                    course.img[0],
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 100,
                    height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 40,
                  ),) '